# GWT, there is a way to ignore the CSS ID's generated when the code is compiled?

Tags: css, gwt, deobfuscation

I'm using GWT in a new project that I'm working on and I'm facing a problem. Some of the CSS rules were defined into the XML file and not into a CSS file.

The problem is that when GWT compiles the code, my name classes defined into my XML file are changed to a new random ID.

Stuffs like **GKA-VPPBPE** or **GKA-VPPBLE**

Is there is a way to keep the original name instead of the generated ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generation of obfuscated css classnames is a feature.

GWT has enabled CSS obfuscation activated by default. This will help reduce the download size and also reduce collision of css-classnames.

You can disable this in general:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty"/>
```

Or for some classes only:

```
@external .myClassName
```

Look here for some more information
https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/disable-obfuscation-in-gwt-css-resources/

Comment: Well done! Thanks for the nice answer and the help! +1 and accepted answer !

Comment: In case anybody else is wondering: In superdev mode, the config property is overriden with pretty by gwt. I researched for an hour now and found an info in the recompiler.java line 510 (https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.8.0-rc2/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/Recompiler.java). The info is already existing in gwt 2.7. I did not check earlier versions.